# Is there a way to extract specific info or lines from a ROS topic?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbridge, rospy, rostopic-echo, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

echo /joint_states has the following output (shortened).

I made a node (using [the rospy tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2FTutorials.2FWritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node)) to subscribe to /joint_states and I want the.py script to print() just the position list for use outside ROS, not the whole topic.

How can I **extract only that one line from the topic?**

Any help appreciated!

```
---
header: 
  seq: 1734
  stamp: 
    secs: 26
    nsecs:  47000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - L_CROTCH_Y
  - L_CROTCH_R
  - L_CROTCH_P
  - L_KNEE_P
  - L_ANKLE_R
  - L_ANKLE_P
  - CHEST_Y
  - LC-AI-linear-joint
  - LC-AO-linear-joint
  - RC-W-linear-joint
  - LC-W-linear-joint
  - RC-E-linear-joint
  - LC-E-linear-joint
position: [0.00015912794687559303, -0.00013126947362762615, -0.5109341293645083, 1.1760409850349758, 0.000248513719677129, -0.621929533407773, -0.000435712016344022, -0.25723620888891585, 0.0001570613057798813, -0.00010196824444583892, -0.5109459927618113, 1.176033708862523, 0.00026405600006946736, -0.6219324270315635, 2.4978990728770677e-06, -0.0017088975996239417, -2.073140234539537, 0.1084099023783044, -0.058023574829095245, -1.0747267840396235, 0.07317868560597149, 0.0032100904000482025, 1.6205784723865542, 0.5235246181475844, -2.073396637452086, -0.10915019469469348, 0.05786516725301176, -1.0742435456501649, -0.07401658373418843, 0.003328953066405395, -1.6208511322518637, 0.5236036706122303, 0.2857, 0.2857, 0.2229, 0.294777, 0.2977, 0.2857, 0.2857, 0.2229, 0.2977, 0.2977, 0.2641, 0.2641, 0.1878, 0.1878]
velocity: [-1.3228298182769372e-05, 0.003776438677399348, -0.0004475842306390639, 0.0005277640174040183, 0.00017784552316915054, -1.3651984069540118e-05, 0.0005193152271762515, -1.614980274114962e-05, -2.00906204147508e-05, 0.003781257562926932, 0.0003987885595227354, -0.0001448261644036203, 0.0001767970472550341, -6.29682030487069e-06, 1.0756488468918085e-05, 8.071757825288712e-06, 0.006530372894968822, -0.0022088213690768304, -0.0016988138511383664, -0.008485019320501625, 0.0011095488166591757, -0.0024041403239194944, 0.0010985414608061655, -0.004589661263847082, -0.006443145635355184, -0.0024326191176086316, -0.0015454480678420079, 0.007643253393764543, 0.0002669792459987253, 0.002038055197724077, 0.0002605698826494082, 0.003338718115727315, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
effort: [-0.003956578081039798, -0.103970838003065, -10.348208900103906, 12.521092591095684, 0.031017161031442676, -0.12736535358104373, 0.024752505226941078, 22.123612918291016, 0.0034862249945595775, -0.2969554758624179, -10.330423298916536, 12.466804055037972, -0.021633696134477715, -0.1281664874752675, -0.00023514434759137692, 1.1822407190049664, 28.710767380445425, 4.002011405040487, 1.9539374192954484, -55.435105205047684, -0.08386314941827289, -17.16595565303094, -0.08274324761003982, -0.0006322724365340204, 29.273691838522797, -3.495521534240986, -1.4834178286291244, -55.63014000109101, -0.09213406138346147, -16.939107019010283, -0.09077836527859873, -0.00042287233021992554, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373672/is-there-a-way-to-extract-specific-info-or-lines-from-a-ros-topic?/) by [etorobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40302/etorobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2021-03-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-03-09**:
What are you looking to extract?

**Comment by [etorobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40302/etorobot/) on 2021-03-09**:
@jayess just this part:

```
position: [0.00015912794687559303, -0.00013126947362762615, -0.5109341293645083, 1.1760409850349758, 0.000248513719677129, -0.621929533407773, -0.000435712016344022, -0.25723620888891585, 0.0001570613057798813, -0.00010196824444583892, -0.5109459927618113, 1.176033708862523, 0.00026405600006946736, -0.6219324270315635, 2.4978990728770677e-06, -0.0017088975996239417, -2.073140234539537, 0.1084099023783044, -0.058023574829095245, -1.0747267840396235, 0.07317868560597149, 0.0032100904000482025, 1.6205784723865542, 0.5235246181475844, -2.073396637452086, -0.10915019469469348, 0.05786516725301176, -1.0742435456501649, -0.07401658373418843, 0.003328953066405395, -1.6208511322518637, 0.5236036706122303, 0.2857, 0.2857, 0.2229, 0.294777, 0.2977, 0.2857, 0.2857, 0.2229, 0.2977, 0.2977, 0.2641, 0.2641, 0.1878, 0.1878]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Via commandline

```
rostopic echo /joint_states | grep position
```

Via code make a subscriber and in the callback, take the message object and `print(msg.position)`

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [etorobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40302/etorobot/) on 2021-03-10**:
thank you! they both work!

print(joint_states.position) in callback gives:

```
 >>= python simplesub.py          
(0.00015512971358007838, -0.00015967116068381712, -0.5109057242141067, 1.1760468735261653, 0.00024737518151100293, -0.6219273124713371, -0.00043378914150490606, -0.25728330147008904, 0.00015295854040879757, -0.00013035336442333807, -0.5109116400316044, 1.176043473406131, 0.00026297911536165907, -0.6219294475672827, 2.3686681173184236e-06, -0.0017019379157545052, -2.0731745346858754, 0.10844604105347311, -0.057998265002420835, -1.0747005312985296, 0.07318421198008158, 0.0032205623245452246, 1.6205839810166822, 0.5235180193010072, -2.0735647804400736, -0.10926420886570778, 0.0577272133804709, -1.0744295533357717, -0.07392402403748027, 0.003115224999999684, -1.6207593400342353, 0.5235428314880762, 0.2857, 0.2857, 0.2229, 0.294777, 0.2977, 0.2857, 0.2857, 0.2229, 0.2977, 0.2977, 0.2641, 0.2641, 0.1878, 0.1878)
```

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-03-10**:
Can you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I made a node (using the rospy tutorial) to subscribe to /joint_states and I want the.py script to print() just the position list for use outside ROS, not the whole topic.

`rostopic echo` can actually print individual fields. The `grep` should not be needed, nor a custom node.

See the [rostopic echo documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_echo):

> `echo <topic-name/field>`
>
> Display specific fields in a message.
>
> ```
> $ rostopic echo /my_topic/field_name
> ```

And see #q54895 for a previous question about this.

For `JointState`:

```
rostopic echo /joint_states/position
```

should work

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [etorobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40302/etorobot/) on 2021-03-10**:
rostopic echo /joint_states/position works in console

```
>>= rostopic echo /joint_states/position
[0.00015846172468917373, -0.00013917082967925174, -0.5109520651984194, 1.176033061817138, 0.0002480363156142424, -0.6219319452419783, -0.00043551693502062657, -0.25721493268895024, 0.00015645224814834745, -0.00010988429784202527, -0.5109659467739442, 1.1760253582176348, 0.0002635422334038843, -0.621934983228341, 2.8759981429691814e-06, -0.001725037542044635, -2.0730975836732286, 0.10848981362952725, -0.057972814677291484, -1.0746624245112641, 0.07318469499950343, 0.00323110174674267, 1.6205845054169492, 0.5236412224584802, -2.073346746902119, -0.1092237021374939, 0.057807670438532716, -1.074215977780912, -0.07399643209973757, 0.0033379011578772684, -1.620831187381248, 0.5237314724596493, 0.2857, 0.2857, 0.2229, 0.294777, 0.2977, 0.2857, 0.2857, 0.2229, 0.2977, 0.2977, 0.2641, 0.2641, 0.1878, 0.1878]
---
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-10**:
Yes, that's what you asked about, isn't it?

Creating a separate node just to print the value of a single field in messages on a topic shouldn't be necessary.

**Comment by [etorobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40302/etorobot/) on 2021-03-10**:
Is there an equivalent of this that can work in code (.py)?
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

- Node subscribes to /joint states to get positions
- Script outputs (outside ROS) the list of positions from /joint_state/position
- External program gives new list of positions
- Node publishes this as JointTrajectoryPoint

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-10**:
This goes much further than simply printing a single field from an incoming message.

You should post a separate question.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-03-11**:
Oh I didn't know that @gvdhoorn, that's really good to know!